# R dangerous streets: match routes and crashes

Tags: r, attribute-joins, road

This is my first attempt with mapping in R.
I have posted my question also in [openTransportDataDemo github](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/openTransportDataDemo/issues/1#issuecomment-850593788)
and I copy it here to hopefully gain broader attention:

My goal is to find the roads where most accidents occur (eg in Leeds) and to see whether this is related to more traffic (ie more vehicles using the road).

Does my approach for joining crash data to roads and to routes make any sense (especially part (b) ).

So, ideally I would like to
a) Match crashes (`stats19` package data)  with roads (OSM data):

```
library(stats19)
library(ggmap)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidygeocoder)
library(sf)

pkgs = c(  "pct",   "osmextract",   "tmap",   "stplanr",   "od" )


lapply(pkgs, library, character.only = TRUE)[length(pkgs)]

tmap_mode("view")

##DATA

## roads from osm

# leeds+buffer

leeds_point = tmaptools::geocode_OSM( "leeds")
c_m_coordiantes = rbind( leeds_point$coords,leeds_point$coords)
c_m_od = od::points_to_od(p = c_m_coordiantes, interzone_only = TRUE)
c_m_desire_line = od::odc_to_sf(c_m_od[-(1:2)])[1, ]
leeds_buffer = stplanr::geo_buffer(c_m_desire_line, dist = 5000)
qtm(leeds_buffer)


### osm roads

library(osmextract)
library(osmdata)

osm_lines = oe_get(leeds_buffer, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quiet = TRUE)

## crash data
crashes = get_stats19(year = 2019, output_format = "sf", lonlat = TRUE)
casualties = get_stats19(year = 2019, type = "casualties")
crashes_combined = inner_join(crashes, casualties)
# table(crashes_combined$casualty_type)
crashes_active = crashes_combined 

crashes_in_area = crashes_active[leeds_buffer, ]


## MATCH roads- crashes

cras_samp=crashes_in_area

points.sf <- st_as_sf(cras_samp, coords = c("longitude","latitude"),crs=4326)


## match crashes to osm roads

cras_samp$road=st_nearest_feature(points.sf$geometry,osm_lines)

dist = st_distance(points.sf$geometry,osm_lines[cras_samp$road,], by_element=TRUE)

## using st_join... not working??
dist2=st_join(st_sf(points.sf),osm_lines)
```

b) Get od data from `stplanr` and convert it to routes.
And then link osm roads to routes.

```
### od data

# get nationwide OD data
od_all <- pct::get_od("west-yorkshire")

centroids_all <- pct::get_centroids_ew() %>% sf::st_transform(4326)

leeds <- pct::pct_regions %>% filter(region_name == "west-yorkshire")
centroids_leeds <- centroids_all[leeds, ]
od_leeds <- od_all %>%
  filter(geo_code1 %in% centroids_leeds$msoa11cd) %>%
  filter(geo_code2 %in% centroids_leeds$msoa11cd)

###

desire_lines <- od2line(od_leeds, centroids_leeds)

desire_lines$distance = as.numeric(st_length(desire_lines))
desire_carshort = dplyr::filter(desire_lines, car_driver > 300 & distance < 5000)

# make routes from od
route_carshort = route(l = desire_carshort, route_fun = route_osrm)

## join routes- osm
route_osm=st_join(route_carshort, osm_lines)

## correct??
## join routes- crash
cras_samp$road2=st_nearest_feature(points.sf$geometry, route_osm)
```

Comment: Hi! Can you add more details on the desired output? You want to create a map displaying car crashes and estimated road traffic, right?